# How do I convert a COM assembly to a CLR Assembly?

Tags: com

How Can I convert a COM server to a CLR Assembly so that I don't have to initially rewrite anything.

Comment: Is this meant as a (very good, comprehensive) self-answer? Because it's missing a question either way!

Comment: It was my way of providing a document of what I did to convert a COM assembly to a CLR assembly.  Just wanted to share with the community.

Comment: That's fine (and encouraged) - it's just '[better etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)' to ask the question that your info answers, then answer your own question. This allows two things - others can add potentially better answers and those looking for an answer can search more easily.

Comment: You're welcome to post your own findings, however please write an actual question here, then move these steps into an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

****I posted this here for the OP, as they posted it origionally as an edit to question.****

Rather than rewriting a COM server (written in 1992 using C++/MFC) in .Net, I have decided to convert it to a CLR assembly.  To take a COM assembly (add32.exe) and use it from a .Net client, we need to create a callable wrapper.  Run all tools with the Visual Studio Command Prompt (as Administrator).

**Step 1: Sign a COM assembly with a strong name**

[image]

**Step 2: Convert definitions found in a COM type library into a CLR assembly**

Convert the definitions found in a COM type library into a CLR assembly using the tool Tlbimp.exe.  The output of Tlbimp.exe is a binary file (an assembly) that contains runtime metadata for the types defined within the original type library.  The output is a DLL file.   I specify a namespace so that we can easily include the metadata in the .Net COM client.

[image]

**Step 3: Use ILDASM.EXE to view the assembly.**

[image]

To use the CLR assembly, we to create a reference for it in the solution.  Browse for the dll file and add it as a reference.

[image]

Clients that use COM objects should import metadata using the namespace created in Step 2.

```
#using "Add32Pkg";
```

Then, to use the COM functionality:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Add32Pkg;

namespace TestAdd32
{
    
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Add32Server Add32 = new Add32Server();
            Add32.Init(201);
        }
    }
}
```